# JSON.parse return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've object , I am extracting it key and access it value through extract key . when I give it try it give me error of undefined . I really tried hard but didn't find any solution could someone please help me how to resolve this issue . Thanks

```js
let data = "{\"id\":14133,\"taskType\":\"viewing\",\"propertyId\":479,\"userId\":640,\"subject\":\"Viewing with Arsalan Ahmed at Bahria Town Phase 2\",\"date\":\"2021-02-18T18:44:00.000Z\"}";

  Object.keys(JSON.parse(data)).map(item=>console.log(JSON.parse(data).item,item))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you :-

You need to access the property using `[]` brackets syntax like so :-

```js
let data = "{\"id\":14133,\"taskType\":\"viewing\",\"propertyId\":479,\"userId\":640,\"subject\":\"Viewing with Arsalan Ahmed at Bahria Town Phase 2\",\"date\":\"2021-02-18T18:44:00.000Z\"}";

  Object.keys(JSON.parse(data)).map(item=>console.log(JSON.parse(data)[item],item))
```

**But Why ?**

Because you're accessing the property `item` which doesn't exist on `data` object. Instead the `item` is a key which can take a value of `id`, `taskType` etc and on the basis of it you need a value from the `data` object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(data)[item]` instead of `JSON.parse(data).item` and it will work. When you use `.item` it will treat it as key = "item", instead when you use `[item]` it will treat it as key = `value of item`.

Try it below.

```js
let data = "{\"id\":14133,\"taskType\":\"viewing\",\"propertyId\":479,\"userId\":640,\"subject\":\"Viewing with Arsalan Ahmed at Bahria Town Phase 2\",\"date\":\"2021-02-18T18:44:00.000Z\"}";

  Object.keys(JSON.parse(data)).map(item=>console.log(JSON.parse(data)[item],item))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the parsed object by the `'item'` property instead of by the variable `item`. Change `.item` to `[item]`.

You should also avoid parsing the data twice (executing `JSON.parse()` twice). Use a variable instead.